# Password protected uploaded PDF page

Tags: uploads, editor, pdf

I created a custom post-type called "designs" for this case. So I want the client to go to his backend and click "Create new Design", this will open up the create page screen, now I want my client to have the option to just upload a number of PDFs and I want to be able to put those PDFs in a layout I desire.

Right now, with wordpress' default behaviour the user can upload PDFs but they will appear as text links and he can just add his own formatting of the page in the editor.

So my question boils down to this:
1) how am i able to limit the user to just inputting his PDFs and thats it?

Bonus question:
Is it also possible to somewhere state implicitly that the PDF has to open in a new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can add a file(s) upload field to your "designs" post type, and hide the regular content editor. Then you can create a custom template for that post type that displays the files attached to the post.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! Is it possible to do this without using an extra plugin? I want to keep the plugin as a last resort!

Comment: @Dennis It would require a plugin, this functionality is not built-in. You can write the plugin that does exactly what you want yourself, but I would not recommend it because it would take you many hours reinventing the wheel. ACF is a developer's plugin and does not add much overhead to your site, and is used by many enterprise sites, I highly recommend it.